# python match chromosome number ignore X, Y, and MT

Tags: python, csv, genetics

I am working with python3 on a linux cluster.  I am having trouble working with chromosome numbers in a table.

I have the following csv (example.csv)

```
1,2,x
3,4,mt
5,6,9
7,8,y
```

I would like to print all lines containing a value of 9 in column #3.

Here is my attempt

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        if 9 == int(line[2]):
            print(line)
```

If I include the `int` it fails due to the presence of MT, Y and X values. But if I exclude `int` it does not find the 9.

Any assistance or clarification on how to query through columns of mixed integers and characters in python is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not try `if '9' == line[2]:`

Answer (score 0):

You should **surround your integer casting with a try/except**, so that you catch the *ValueError*:

```
import csv
with open('example.csv', 'rb') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        try:
            if 9 == int(line[2]):
                print(line)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

This works :)